# PostgresDB with psycopg2 query executing successfully but sometimes updating the record and sometimes not

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, psycopg2

I am trying to update PostgresDB with psycopg2 with below query, it is executing successfully but sometimes it is not updating the record (sometimes updating and sometimes not). Can someone help me?

Below code printed 'Order status updated' but returned rowcount =0.

```
def update_order_status(order_id, executed_at, order_executed, exec_completed, conn_prod):
    
    rowcount = 0
    sql = """UPDATE orders SET status = %s, executed_type = %s, executed_at= %s 
            WHERE order_id = %s"""
    try:    
        cur = conn_prod.cursor()
        cur.execute(sql, (order_executed, exec_completed, executed_at, order_id))
        conn_prod.commit()
        rowcount = cur.rowcount
        cur.close()
        print('Order status updated')
        return rowcount
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        conn_prod.rollback()
        return rowcount
        
count = update_order_status('1234', '2021-10-26 13:30:18+00', 'COMPLETED', 'FULL', conn_prod)
```

Comment: Are you hitting the `Exception` portion of the code?

Answer (score 0):

Just move the `cur.close()` to finally block

```
def update_order_status(order_id, executed_at, order_executed, exec_completed, conn_prod):
    
    rowcount = 0
    sql = """UPDATE orders SET status = %s, executed_type = %s, executed_at= %s 
            WHERE order_id = %s"""
    cur = conn_prod.cursor()
    try:    
        cur.execute(sql, (order_executed, exec_completed, executed_at, order_id))
        conn_prod.commit()
        rowcount = cur.rowcount
        print('Order status updated')
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        conn_prod.rollback()
    finally:
        cur.close()
    return rowcount 
        
count = update_order_status('1234', '2021-10-26 13:30:18+00', 'COMPLETED', 'FULL', conn_prod)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Anand. How does it make difference if I move cur.close() to finally block? (just wanted to understand the reason)

Comment: Cursor is not being closed in the exception block it is only closed in try block. So if you encountered any error it will not be closed.

Comment: Any chance it has helped you?

Comment: Doubt that this has anything to do with it, the `conn_prod.commit()` is the important part.

Comment: Code executed without any errors but not updated in the table (if i consider closing curser might cause problem). My application will be available between 9am-3pm (IST), will test and update the results.

Comment: Above code printed 'Order status updated' also but returned rowcount =0).

Comment: My bad updated the code